# Is there a way to force clicks on overflow content to fire a click event

Tags: jquery, html, css

The major problem I am trying to solve: be able to have the drop down options width larger than the area where the selected value is shown, specifically in IE7. After googling for awhile, I decided to try and write my own to give me more ability to style it.

What I have done is use an input text box to display the selected value. The input's width is inherited from its parent div. I then dynamically build unordered list of the drop down options. To have the options extend past the containing div's width I used negative margins and overflow-x: visible.

Where I am running into problems is that clicks and scrolling aren't respected in the area of each drop down option that extends past the width of the parent div. Is there a way to get this to work?

In case it matters, I'm using jQuery to handle the events. I have set a delegated click handler on the ul element for each li element.

The static html:

```
<div id="dropDownDiv" style="width: 155px;">
  <input type="text" />
</div>

<script>
    $(createDropDown("dropDownDiv")):
</script>
```

The functions to create the drop downs:

```
function creatDropDown(inputId) {
  var fragment = $(document.createElement('ul')),
      countryList = ${countriesJS};

  for(var i = countryList.length-1; i >= 0; i=i-1) {
    $("<li code='" + countryList[i][1] + "'>" + countryList[i][0] + "</li>").prependTo(fragment);
  }

  fragment.addClass("hidden menuOptions");
  $(inputId).append(fragment);
  $(inputId).on("click", function(e) {fragment.removeClass("hidden");});
  fragment.on("click", "li", handler);
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle. My example actually works in jsFiddle, but doesn't in iE7.
http://jsfiddle.net/rpmc22/vAP56/

this is a quick sketch. Essentially any click that occurs right of the red line does not fire a click event.
[image: drop down sketch]

Comment: I don't think so it is possible.

Comment: you should mock up what you're trying to do and upload a jpg. Your description is pretty confusing. Please also include some sample code. Are you talking about a SELECT element in a FORM?

Comment: The unordered list, make it the sibling of your parent div to input field and give it proper height & width. If you can put your code of JSfiddle, that would be of more help.

Comment: can you have a sketch for better explaining?

Comment: This is my first time posting a question and because my reputation is so low I can't post images.

Comment: could you show an example such as in jsfiddle for us to better understand what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you can avoid, but when you do the click you can calculate the dimensions of the divs, and if is inside you do what you want, if not, nothing happens.

here is a link that will help you: [Mouse Position](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position)

```
$("#element").click(function(e){

    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    if(x < XX && y < YY) {
        /*do you code*/
    }
    else {
        /*nothing*/
    }
   });
```

good luck

greetings